# Best Practice for AWS Elastic Beanstalk Permission

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am new to AWS Elastic Beanstalk and still learning about it. Please share the best practice you know.

"`eb deploy`" uploaded the Django app to AWS. However, '`./manage makemigrations`' will have **permission denied** error like this

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 338, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 330, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 390, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 441, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/makemigrations.py", line 143, in handle
    self.write_migration_files(changes)
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/makemigrations.py", line 172, in write_migration_files
    with open(writer.path, "wb") as fh:
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/opt/python/bundle/3/app/myproj/myapp/migrations/0001_initial.py'
```

NOTE the user is ec2-user who only owns read permission to '`/opt/python/bundle/3/app/myproj/myapp/migrations/`'. Using root user can successfully execute migrations, however, that has security concerns.

Another similar issue is, 
ec2-user does not have WRITE access to '`/var/log/`', where shall the log files be stored? Stored inside `/home/ec2-user`? The home directory will be wiped out if the environment is terminated, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not be calling makemigrations on your EB instance.
makemigrations is something you call as part of development, and then put all resulting files (like the "0001_initial.py") under version control, and deployed as part of `eb deploy`.

On your .ebextensions, you only need to call "migrate" which only writes to the database (while doing the actual migration of data):

```
container_commands:
   01_migrate:
     command: "django-admin.py migrate --noinput"
     leader_only: true
```

Some of the examples out there also recommend calling collectstatics on your .ebextensions, but I recommend against it. Assuming you are using something like django-storages and storing all statics on S3 (or better, CloudFront), then it is better to call collectstatics on your own local machine as part of development. e.g.

```
python manage.py collecstatics
eb deploy
```

I don't have a real question to the logs question. I simply use eb logs so I just print what I want to see to the console, and EB will take care of those logs. But I do know you have permissions to write to /tmp so that can be a location for logs.